# How to create Java object in Unity3d (using AndroidJavaObject or AndroidJNI.NewObject)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

What's the difference between creating the object using `AndroidJavaObject` and  `AndroidJNI.NewObject`?

```
new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_SEND);
```

vs

```
IntPtr intentClass = AndroidJNI.FindClass("android.content.Intent");
IntPtr intentConstructor = AndroidJNI.GetMethodID(IntentClass,"<init>","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");


jvalue[] intentParameters = new jvalue[1];
intentParameters[0] = ACTION_SEND;
IntPtr intentObject = AndroidJNI.NewObject(intentClass, intentConstructor, intentParameters);
```

Is `AndroidJavaObject` just a shorter version or there are any downsides?

Comment: Perhaps the `AndroidJavaObject` constructor always calls `FindClass` internally without any kind of caching. There are times where you might prefer just calling `FindClass` once and saving the result as a global reference for repeated use (e.g. trying to use `FindClass` for non-system classes on a purely native thread can be problematic).

Comment: @Michael yeh, inside it does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decompile this class, you will see that it does the same thing:

```
private void _AndroidJavaObject(string className, params object[] args)
{
  this.DebugPrint("Creating AndroidJavaObject from " + className);
  if (args == null)
    args = new object[1];
  using (AndroidJavaObject @class = AndroidJavaObject.FindClass(className))
  {
    this.m_jclass = new GlobalJavaObjectRef(@class.GetRawObject());
    jvalue[] jniArgArray = AndroidJNIHelper.CreateJNIArgArray(args);
    try
    {
      IntPtr num = AndroidJNISafe.NewObject((IntPtr) this.m_jclass, AndroidJNIHelper.GetConstructorID((IntPtr) this.m_jclass, args), jniArgArray);
      this.m_jobject = new GlobalJavaObjectRef(num);
      AndroidJNISafe.DeleteLocalRef(num);
    }
    finally
    {
      AndroidJNIHelper.DeleteJNIArgArray(args, jniArgArray);
    }
  }
}
```